# matlab Static methods are unnecessary, right?

Tags: matlab, class, methods, static-methods, matlab-deployment

I researched [static methods](https://ww2.mathworks.cn/help/matlab/matlab_oop/static-methods.html?searchHighlight=static%20methods&s_tid=srchtitle_support_results_1_static%2520methods) and feel that static methods are non-essential in matlab.There would be no inconvenience if matlab did not provide a static method.**I wonder if my above opinion is correct?**
The benefit of static methods is "not related to the specific object", only related to classes.Can be called inside the class.Also can be called by the object！
I found I can do what the static method does with ordinary methods！
Here's a simple example.method1  didn't use input argument. I can use method1 in constructor.Although the program uses 'obj.method1' to call method1, this does not mean that method1 is related to any specific object.

```
classdef test<handle     
    properties
        X
        Y
    end
    
    methods
        function obj = test(inputArg1,inputArg2)
            obj.X = inputArg1 + inputArg2;
            obj.Y=obj.method1(inputArg2);
        end
    end
    methods
        function value = method1(obj,inputArg)
            value = 3 + 3;
        end
    end    
end
```

Here's a more complex example.Use object-oriented programming method to draw three-dimensional surface graph. It is required to define two classes, one of which stores the data of the function, and uses a static method to calculate the grid coordinates of the interval in this class; the function of the other class is to draw a three-dimensional surface map, and the drawing process is realized by a static method.

@MfunEval/MfunEval.m

```
classdef  MfunEval
        properties
          HFun;    
          Lm = [-2*pi 2*pi];     
        end
        properties (Dependent = true)
          Data;          
        end
        methods
           function obj = MfunEval(fun_handle,limits)   %Constructor
               obj.HFun = fun_handle;
               obj.Lm = limits;
           end
           function data = get.Data(obj)      %
             [x,y] = MfunEval.grid(obj.Lm);  
             z= obj.HFun(x,y);
             data.X = x;
             data.Y = y;
             data.Z = z;
           end
        end
        methods (Static)      %Static methods
           function [x,y] = grid(lim)   
                step = (lim(2)-lim(1))/50;
               [x,y] = meshgrid(lim(1):step:lim(2));
           end
        end
    end
```

@MfunView/MfunView.m

```
classdef MfunView
        properties
          FunObj          
          HSurf           
        end
        methods
           function obj = MfunView(fobj)  %Constructor
             obj.FunObj= fobj;
           end
        end  
        methods (Static = true)           %
            createViews(a)                %
        end  
    end
```

@MfunView/ createViews.m

```
function  createViews(funevalobj)
      viewobj=MfunView(funevalobj);
      viewobj.HSurf = surf(viewobj.FunObj.Data.X,...
          viewobj.FunObj.Data.Y,...
          viewobj.FunObj.Data.Z);
      shading interp;
    end
```

**I modified @MfunEval/MfunEval.m Replaced MfunEval.grid with obj.grid.I change the static method to a normal method. The program can still run!**

```
classdef  MfunEval
    properties
        HFun;    
        Lm = [-2*pi 2*pi];    
    end
    properties (Dependent = true)
        Data;          
    end
    methods
        function obj = MfunEval(fun_handle,limits)   %Constructor
            obj.HFun = fun_handle;
            obj.Lm = limits;
        end
        function data = get.Data(obj)      
            %[x,y] = MfunEval.grid(obj.Lm);
            [x,y] = obj.grid(obj.Lm);  %call grid function
            z= obj.HFun(x,y);
            data.X = x;
            data.Y = y;
            data.Z = z;
        end
    end
    methods %(Static)      %change Static
        function [x,y] = grid(obj,lim)    
            step = (lim(2)-lim(1))/50;
            [x,y] = meshgrid(lim(1):step:lim(2));
        end
    end
end
```

Comment: Cross-posted at https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/2006482-static-methods-are-unnecessary-right?s_tid=srchtitle

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are confusing the use-case of static methods.

Of course you can use normal methods and static methods *inside* a class.
The point of a static method is to be used *outside* of the class, without creating an object.

e.g.

```
classdef  MfunEval
        properties
          Lm;
          very_large_matrix;    
        end
        properties (Dependent = true)
          Data;          
        end
        methods
           function obj = MfunEval()   %Constructor
               obj.Lm = MfunEval.largeLim(); % this can be also non-static, doesn't matter, its INSIDE the object already.
               obj.Lm = obj.largeLim(); % equivalent to above. 
               obj.very_large_matrix = zeros(10000000000000000000,100000000000000000);
              
           end
        end
        methods (Static)      %Static methods
           function [lim]= largeLim()  
               lim=[-100, 100]
           end
        end
        methods (Static)      %Static methods
           function [lim]= smallLim()  
               lim=[-2, 2]
           end
        end
    end
```

For the example here, the fact that the method is static or not inside the constructor, its irrelevant. However, in your main code, you can now do

```
lim=MfunEval.smallLim() % does not construct an object, just calls the function
a=MfunEval; % Ouch! It has created a 1000000000000x10000000000 zeros matrix and you run out of memory
lim=a.smallLim() % works, but a needs to have been instantiated, so you provably ran out of memory.
```

In essence, `static` methods have nothing to do with how you use them *inside* a class/object, and all about how you can use them outside the class.

Example of use: say you have a very complex class that takes as initialization 30 variables. You could make a static method called `default_parameters()` that outputs the default values of these parameters, so the user can modify them, and then give them as an input to the constructor.

In general, a function of a class that does not need the values of the properties of a class *can be* a static method. Often, these are made to be static methods, not because you *need* them to be static, but because it makes conceptually sense that they are. Most of OOP is just about organizing your code in logical and structured ways anyway.